# What program should I use to handle large high frequency data?

Tags: limit-order-book, high-frequency-data

I am going to do research about exchange. For this purpose I get daily data for all stocks to reconstruct order book. I have data on 900 trading days. Each day have data about ticker, timestamp, action - B or S, order ID, type of action - 0 cancel order, 1 place order, 2 deal, price, volume. Each day consists of about 50 million lines, so it takes a long time to do it in Python. I tried to use QuestDb and for now it looks like a best option for me. Perhaps there are some other extensions over SQL? Or some special languages to work with this data type?

As a result, I want to calculate the average spread for each ticker during the day. For this I need to restore order book, I tried to do it in Python, but because I have not snapshot, but dynamic data in which I need to take into account 3 actions to calculate the spread - someone put a better order, someone executed a market order, the owner of the best order canceled it. Due to the fact that I have big data it is difficult to take everything into account when calculating the spread. What is the best way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The right thing is indeed some SQL type language. I strongly recommend SAS since it has good documentation and people have been using it in finance for a long time.

With 45 billion data points that's your best bet. If you have access to a cluster you can do it in parallel (i.e. you load each day at a time into each node of the cluster). So you can do 900 at a time. This should be the fastest way, but you need to have access to a cluster that allows you to do this (which can get expensive). If you give me an estimate of how long it takes to run the average for 1 day using 1 core and how much ram memory it requires, I/you can get an estimate of an AWS cost for the task.

Comment: Yeah, I think it will be expensive to do via clusters. I am doing this as a non-profit project.